# How to add a shortcut in a VS2010 setup project which does not reevaluate installed files

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, deployment-project

**The situation**: I've got a Windows Desktop application that connects to various services (one at a time) to perform various calls. My application works the same way no matter which service it connects to. Which service it should connect to at any time is defined in an application.config file.

In order to switch between services, I've created a couple of windows .bat-files, each of which replaces the existing .config file with the new one (service endpoint) to use.

For all of this, I've created an installer (an MSI, using the "Setup Project" template in Visual Studio 2010). This installer also creates shortcuts to:

1. the application itself
2. the first .bat file (which sets the config file with the "default" service endpoint)
3. the second .bat file. (which replaces the config file with the alternative one)

**The problem**: Each time I run any of these (the app or the bat files) via the shortcuts, they seem to "reevalueate" the installed files before actually running the target. This is no problem as long as I'm using the default .config file, as that was the way it was installed. If I've run the second .bat file however, and am trying to run the application so it connects to the second service, then starting the application via the shortcut causes the .config-file to be reverted, and I end up connecting to the first service instead.

I'm able to create my own shortcuts manually, both to the .bat files and to the application itself, and they work fine. I'd like this to happen automatically however, without messing up any changes to other files.


Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance, 
-Kjartan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your deployment project has what is known as an "advertised shortcut". There are several ways to disable those, see the following link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/b57f1d84-9b0c-4c29-b140-0555f92ffed8

Answer (score 0):

Thanks George. This was kind of annoying, and I'm surprised there does not seem to be a good way to disable this by default. Thought I'd share the solution we went with in the end, even if it is not perfect: We will run the installer from command prompt with the following parameter, thus generating "normal" shortcuts.

**Setup.exe DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1**

This means that we can't let our users install the app as they normally would, with a simple double-click. It does however mean that we (the programers) won't have to edit the generated installer using some external tool each time we do a new deployment; an acceptable trade-off, since this is an in-house only application.

Thanks again, 
-Kjartan